# How to make is so a square is limited to stay in another square in css when screen resizes

Tags: html, css

I have some squares and I want the smaller squares to stay in the bigger square when you make the screen smaller but so far all they do is overlap

HTML

```
 <div id="Frame">
  <div id="box1">box1</div>
  <div id="box2">box2</div>
  <div id="box3">box3</div>
  <div id="box4">box4</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#Frame {
 background-color: pink;
 width: 90%;
 height: 700px;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

#box1 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#box2 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-left: 48%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#box3 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-top: 350px;
 margin-left: 5%;
}

#box4 {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-left: 48%;
 margin-top: 360px;
}
```

[Here's a link to the jsfiddle with my code](https://jsfiddle.net/A_Burger_Dog/qpdxw4e7/1)

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

These aren't actual squares, just boxes with auto widths but you can play with the dimensions.  You could also add `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` to `.grid div` and it will give you squares but then it won't always fit every viewport perfectly (plus not sure all browsers support this).  Anyway...this should get you started.
`

```css
body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .grid {

      background: #FFBDBD;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      grid-row: auto auto;
      grid-gap: 24px;
      padding: 24px;
    }

    .grid div {
      background: #7FB9D5;
      color: #00537C;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 24px;


    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div>box1</div>
    <div>box2</div>
    <div>box3</div>
    <div>box4</div>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```